# Self-Referencing a Common Database Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a site which you send music data to server it saves it and gives you a unique 'flash'. I want to self-reference the song data to the flash. But I will need a `flash_id` field in the song table but as I would like one song entry for the same song this won't work (I would like a count of how many times the song has been 'flashed')

Each Flash is like a tweet or post. It is connected to the user

Thanks

Song Model

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :flash
end
```

Flash Model

```
class Flash < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :song
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say, one song can be "flashed" several times, and I asume one flash flashes exactly one song.
So your relation has to be the other way round: flash has to contain the song_id.
You can make Rails keep a cached count of the flashes of each song, if `song` has a column `flashes_count`:

Song Model

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flashes
end
```

Flash Model

```
class Flash < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :song, counter_cache: true
end
```